# How to decrypt data and determine encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption

### I'm trying to decrypt the following table:

*Date          Label      Code*

26.09.2018    a   41310001075389700

27.09.2018   a   448160001075586000

02.10.2018   a   576990001074818000

28.09.2018   a   32270001075371700

11.10.2018   a   511660001074989852

01.10.2018   a   188260001074810000

09.10.2018   a   395980001075290000

10.10.2018   a   461080001075350000

11.09.2018   a   119400001074791000

13.09.2018   a   451710001075704000

17.09.2018   a   245950001074796000

18.09.2018   a   260001074888965

20.09.2018   a   390150001074855000

24.09.2018   a   558580001074794000

25.09.2018   a   322670001074798000

11.10.2018   a   285750001075053852

19.09.2018   a   15400001074929400

03.10.2018   a   550850001074820000

28.09.2018   a   359980001075372000

27.09.2018   b   445000000272901000

11.10.2018   b   86250000272927000

10.09.2018   b   490632000272892000

11.09.2018   b   234130000272888574

26.09.2018   b   007910000273087757

28.09.2018   b   459100000272797000

12.09.2018   b   085370000272864511

17.09.2018   b   80150000272953600

18.09.2018   b   120860000273659000

01.10.2018   b   243850000272906000

04.10.2018   b   315990000272946000

02.10.2018   b   54630000272868600

08.10.2018   b   649470000272938000

13.09.2018   b   514820000272867584

02.10.2018   b   14390000273446600

29.09.2018   b   177190000272714000

05.10.2018   b   423250000272924000

10.10.2018   b   613380000272892000

Maximum understandable information for me are the central part in any "Code" possibly connected to "Label", e.g. "a" :  "******107******" and "b" : "*****27*****". If anyone has idea, I'd be very happy.

The data need to be decrypted is the net between "Label" and "Code".

Comment: So you don't know the algorithm and you don't have a decryption key?

Comment: In a word, you can't. Not without more information, anyway. Your data consists of a date, and 18 decimal digits (about 60 bits) of encrypted data. It could be anything, and 60 bits is not enough to tell you anything about its source, crypto algorithm, or even if it's just a truncated one-way hash code.